# Argument of type 'NextHandleFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I've got TypeScript up and running with a basic Express server, and I'm running into an issue.

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express, { Express } from 'express';

const app: Express = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Error 1
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Error 2
```

**Error 1 is this:**

> Property 'pop' is missing in type 'NextHandleFunction'. [2345]

So `bodyParser.json()` is returning a `createServer.NextHandleFunction` but doesn't have the `pop` property. `NextHandleFunction` is defined like this in `@types/connect`:

```
export type NextHandleFunction = (req: http.IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse, next: NextFunction) => void;
```

Yep, no `pop`. But what are my options for fixing this?

**Error 2 is this:**

> Type 'NextHandleFunction' is not assignable to type '(string | RegExp)[]'. [2345]

Here, `bodyParser.urlencoded()` is also returning a `createServer.NextHandleFunction`, but that's not the type `app.use()` is looking for.

Again, not sure about my options here.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.0",
    "@types/connect": "^3.4.32",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.16.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-serve-static-core": "^0.1.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
}
```

Comment: You imported the type definitions through npm for node and express right?

Comment: Yep, npm install --save @types/<whatever>

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue @jacobsowles

Comment: Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: I also ran into this `Argument of type 'NextHandleFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'` problem when upgrading from "@types/node" v15.6.1 to v16.11.7. Seems like modern @types/node doesn't work well with "@types/express" v4.17.13.

Answer (score 25):

I was able to fix the error this way:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express, { Express, RequestHandler } from 'express';

const app: Express = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json() as RequestHandler);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }) as RequestHandler);
```

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't have to cast your middleware, as suggested in the other answers.  I believe there may have been some incompatibility between minor `@types/*` package versions.  After removing some type-package dependencies, deleting `node_modules/@types`, and explicitly installing `@types/express`, `@types/express-serve-static-core`, and `@types/cookie-parser` (you may not need that one), I wound up with (among other things)

```json
        "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.10",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.12",
        "@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.17.21",
```

I am now able to write

```
import {json, urlencoded} from "express";

...

app.use(urlencoded({extended: false}));

...

app.post("./", json(), this.doPost.bind(this));
```

These type-check without an explicit cast.  I'm not sure exactly what was wrong with the older packages, or if there was some kind of transitive dep de-dupe that picked the wrong combination, but the versions above seem to work together correctly.

Comment: To add to this one, I had the same issue. Setting @types/express and express as the exact same versions helped fix it as of "4.17.1". When @types/express was set to "4.17.3" and express as "4.17.1" it gave Typescript errors.

Comment: `"@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.17.21"` is the solution to this problem. It's a transient dependency that you need to override.

Comment: After the issue still remained for me, I figured out that for some odd reason `@types/body-parser` was still in my `yarn.lock`, so I just deleted it, did a fresh `yarn install` and finally it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Removing **@types/express** and **@types/express-serve-static-core** helped me get rid of those errors, and types are also bundled in express by default. So, don't hesitate to remove them. Also, you don't need body-parser anymore, as json and url-encoded middleware are bundled in express it-self.

Comment: I upvoted this because I tried what you suggested and my project still seemed to work.  It turns out this is wrong. Types are **not** bundled with express, you do still need `@types/express` -- I just accidentally still had them as a transitive dependency through `@types/cookie-parser` which I hadn't removed.  The info about removing `body-parser` is accurate, though.

Comment: Previous commenter is right. TS types are not bundled with express.

Answer (score 6):

Add this import statement as below in app.ts.

```
import express, { RequestHandler } from 'express';
```

also change the express.json() and express.urlencoded({ extended: true }) as below.

```
this.app.use(express.json() as RequestHandler);
this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }) as RequestHandler);
```

Comment: I did not downvote but as you can see from my answer, typecasting is not required and might hide other bugs that are introduced later.  It looks like the OP's bug was caused by bad/incompatible types that have since been fixed.